# MongoTimeoutException Message: Timed out while waiting to connect after 10000 ms

Tags: mongodb, grails, groovy, grails-orm

I'm using gorm in grails to connect to MongoDB. I'm getting MongoTimeOutException.
I'm able to successfully connect to MongoDb using mongo java driver stand alone program.
Why am i not able to connect through Grails GORM plugin?

Can someone help?
The below is the configuration

```
grails {
    mongo {
      host = "localhost"
      port = 27107
      databaseName = "test"
     options{
         connectionsPerHost=20
     }
    }
  }
```

The below is domain class

```
class Device {


    String deviceType
    String deviceId
    int primary

    static constraints = {

    }
}
```

The below is the exception trace

```
| Error 2014-11-09 16:10:39,620 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - MongoTimeoutException occurred when processing request: [GET] /devices/Device

Timed out while waiting to connect after 10000 ms. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Timed out while waiting to connect after 10000 ms
    Line | Method
->>  131 | getDescription        in com.mongodb.BaseCluster
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    396 | getClusterDescription in com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector
|    569 | getType . . . . . . . in     ''
|    370 | isMongosConnection    in     ''
|    645 | isMongosConnection .  in com.mongodb.Mongo
|    454 | _check                in com.mongodb.DBCursor
|    546 | _hasNext . . . . . .  in     ''
|    571 | hasNext               in     ''
|   1893 | hasNext . . . . . . . in org.grails.datastore.mapping.mongo.query.MongoQuery$MongoResultList$1
|      8 | index                 in ewents.DeviceController
|    198 | doFilter . . . . . .  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter              in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|    895 | runTask . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|    918 | run                   in     ''
^    695 | run . . . . . . . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

or could someone share sample Grails example with GORM support? Am basically new to this Grails.

Comment: Obviously, grails can not connect to the MongoDB server at localhost:27017. Have you tried to access it via the mongo shell or telnet?

Comment: Yes, am able to access via mongo shell. But, why can't Grails connect to localhost:27017 when a stand alone Java class is able to?

Comment: Both are on the same machine, I assume? Please give the exact command line you are using to connect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out the issue. It's my bad, given the port number as 27107 instead of 27017 and i took a day to figure this out. LOL

Comment: Killed 3 hours on the same issue. Thanks!

Comment: Ditto, hard to see that transpose.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and it showed out that in my test case, I didn't get the properties from where I expected. (My host contained a quotation mark in teh string...)

My suggestion for developers with this issue in the future is to set a breakpoint in com.mongodb.mongo.java in method "boolean isMongosConnection()" and see what host and port that is actually used.